# Material glitches at joints when using Bevel modifier?

Tags: bevel

I've applied all my other modifiers and applied all transformations and I'm just left with a Bevel modifier for my object. And this modifier is causing weird glitches at joints that involve faces with different materials (see that odd little rhombus of red at the bottom right):

[image]

I've got *Outer Miter* set to *Arc* and have *Harden Normals* ticked. I'm pretty sure there are no geometry issues (overlapping edges etc.). Using *Limited Dissolve* and *Merge by Distance* doesn't improve the situation and in wireframe mode, you can see the mesh is super simple.

With the Bevel modifier disabled, everything looks normal:

[image]

And if I set *Outer Miter* to *Sharp*, I don't get the look I want at the joints but the odd glitch goes away:

[image]

So if I don't want *Sharp* joints, how can I solve the odd glitch shown up above? What's causing it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my `.blend` file (created using Blender 3.1.0)...

[image]

---

#### Update

And I don't believe it's an n-gon issue either. If I add and apply a Triangulate modifier (with quad and n-gon method set to *Beauty*) I still see this issue:

[image]

The faces above are all triangles and I've increased the bevel amount to make the "glitch" even more obvious.

Comment: If I APPLY the modifier, I can see where the material is applied incorrectly.  With Strength set to -1, the closest material should be applied and there are errors.   Mitre Outer changed to "Sharp" does a better job but not great.  I would report this as a bug.   You could also APPLY the modifier and manually apply the correct material to the errant faces until this bug is fixed.

Comment: Agree with @tempdev.. it looks like a bug. But at least a consistent, and therefore traceable bug. It seems to be in the 'Automatic' (-1) material offset setting, which should split the bevel down the middle at material boundaries. It's getting the boundary 1-off at the end of a patch/arc spread of faces. Have you reported it yet?

Comment: yeah agree definitely a bug with the automatic material offset, it gets confused by the boundaries. but maybe you want to consider using material offset index 0 or 1 instead of automatic, it actually makes it look nice as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback from everyone. I've now logged this as a bug - https://developer.blender.org/T97000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely caused by a bug, which you should report here: https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/

In the meantime you could apply the materials, as this seems to fix the issue.